# Libgdx Table position is not setting right

Tags: java, libgdx

The issue I am having is creating a table with a scrollpane on the stage next to the Monster, IE right click the monster, create the table's position based on the Monster.

I've tried setting it to 1,1 or the monsters positon, but the table ALWAYS goes to the far right, completely missing the coords, even setting it to 1,1 puts it at like 682, 364.

```
ContextManager.getTable().setPosition(1, 1);
```

ive tried

```
ContextManager.getTable().setPosition(monster.x, monster.y);
```

Ive added it to the stage and its using the stage, so it should be at 1,1 of the stage not some other random stop, and i am not setting the position anywhere else so its not being overridden

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example (code) that shows your problem?

Comment: The issue was I was using table.setFillParent(true); so it was using viewport coords